# Buscar coincidencias entre dos Arrays y crear uno nuevo con los ítems que no coinciden

Tags: javascript

estoy creando una plataforma que da premios a los usuarios. Mi problema viene cuando tengo que mirar que premios tienen ya y cuales puedo darles (para no repetir los premios). Tengo un array con todos los disponibles y otro con los que ya tienen.

```
var availableAvatar =['Csimple','Calien','Ccosmonaut','CgreenAereal','ChappyBirthday']
var userAvatars=['Ccosmonaut','ChappyBirthday']
```

He intentado usar el método filtre, pero no he conseguido crear un array con los que no coinciden.

Lo que necesito:

```
var possibleAward=['Csimple','Calien','CgreenAereal']
var random = avatarP[Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleAward.length)];
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: if you need a help, you have to translate your question, this is a Stackoverflow in spanish, regards.

Comment: Buenas, justo ahora voy a traducirlo. Quería subirlo al normal, pero no me he dado cuenta y lo he puesto aquí. Gracias por decírmelo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podes hacerlo combinando `filter` e `includes`. Del array 1 voy a FILTRAR todos los elementos que NO estén INCLUIDOS en el array 2

```js
var arr1 = ['Csimple','Calien','Ccosmonaut','CgreenAereal','ChappyBirthday']
var arr2 = ['Ccosmonaut','ChappyBirthday']


let res = arr1.filter(e => !arr2.includes(e));



console.log(res)
```